# Chrome extension: Keep it at same state in different tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to make a chrome extension, and I am wondering how to make it that it stays in the same place (does not reload in each tab).

For example my chrome extension is a draggable div with "hello world" in in.

On default it would have position absolute and be placed top: 0; left: 0;

Now let's say I drag it on one tab to another position, and then switch to other chrome tab, it will reload and have it's default positioning. I wan't it to have the state from previous tab and not reload.

Comment: Haven't tested it out myself, but this looks like it could be used to hold the co-ordinates: [chrome.storage page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), so you could save the coordinates, and on every load fetch the data from the storage (if it is found, else set the default to 0, 0)

Comment: Cool. Thank You Rani :)